# Were there any Russian or Soviet moviemakers who were widely imitated by Western ones?

Tags: reference, remake

It's well known that many Western moviemakers respect and love foreign moviemakers and liberally borrow/steal/copy/homage ideas and scenes.

Anything from Tarantino and Wuxia movies, to Lucas and Kurosawa.

However, I couldn't find any instance of a Russian or Soviet moviemaker that was notably borrowed from.

Are there any?

A single notable example is enough for a yes answer, but for a no answer I'll need a link to a good research publication analyzing the topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**YES**

**Example**: The "Odessa Steps sequence" in *Battleship Potemkin* by Eisenstein.

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battleship_Potemkin#The_Odessa_Steps_sequence) lists MANY movies that borrowed, in my opinion the most famous was "*The Untouchables*".

> The scene is perhaps the best example of Eisenstein's theory on montage, and many films pay homage to the scene, including Terry Gilliam's *Brazil*, Francis Ford Coppola's *The Godfather*, Brian De Palma's *The Untouchables*, Tibor Takacs' *Deathline*, Laurel and Hardy's *The Music Box*, George Lucas's *Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*...

Seems **notable** enough :)

Comment: So now I am wondering what scene in Brazil is inspired by this.

Comment: I wonder which part of Eisenstein was Jar-Jar Binks a homage to...

Comment: Who's Jar-Jar Binks? ;-)