# What exactly was the homage to Eisenstein in "The Godfather"?

Tags: the-godfather

While answering [a previous question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/1065/1887), I noticed that "*The Godfather*" was listed as an example of a movie that paid homage to Eisenstein's "Odessa Steps Sequence" from "*Battleship Potemkin*", according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battleship_Potemkin#The_Odessa_Steps_sequence).

I don't seem to recall anything like that in the movie.

**What exactly was that homage?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [The Odessa Steps and Its Descendants](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH1tO2D3LCI) on YouTube: 
The relevant scene shows part of the assassination of the heads of the five families, which occurs in the movie near the very end while Michael is at the baptism ceremony.
Two relevant images are the steps themselves as a location for death, and the close-up of a ravaged eye (*and* a pair of shattered eyeglasses).
In the Godfather, the cop on the steps kills family head by shooting him in the back; a second shoots Moe Green in the eye, through his eyeglasses while he is getting a massage.